# Donde debo almacenar mis imágenes en vuex? /Assets o /static y porque?

Tags: vue.js, web, webpack, vuex

No entiendo la diferencia y cuál debería usar.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.